# What causes the failure of this return statement inside a React 18 template?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

I have been working on an SPA with **React 18** and **The Movie Database (TMDB) API**.

I have a component intended to display *movie trailers*, that I use on the movie details page like this:

```
{trailers.length ?
  <>
    <div className="mb-3">
      <h2 className="section-title">Trailers</h2>
      <TrailerCarousel trailers={trailers} />
    </div>
  </> : <></>
}
```

In the Trailercarousel.jsx file I have:

```
import './Trailercarousel.css';

function Trailercarousel({ trailers }) {
  return (
    <div id="trailersCarousel" className="carousel slide" data-bs-interval="false">
      {trailers.length > 1 ?
        <>
          <ol className="carousel-indicators">
            return trailers.slice(0, maxCarouselItems).map((video, index) => (
              <li
                key="video.id"
                data-bs-target="#trailersCarousel"
                data-bs-slide-to="`${index}`"
                className="{ active: index === 0 }"
              >
                {index + 1}
              </li>
            ));
          </ol>
        </> : <></>
      }

      <div className="carousel-inner">
        return trailers.slice(0, 5).map((video, index) => (
          <div
            key="video.id"
            className="carousel-item"
            activeclassname="{ active: index === 0 }"
          >
            <iframe
              className="embed-responsive-item"
              src="`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${video.key}`"
            ></iframe>
          </div>
        ));
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Trailercarousel;
```

#### The problem

The expression below does **not** return the `<li>` elements:

```
return trailers.slice(0, maxCarouselItems).map((video, index) => (
  <li
    key="video.id"
    data-bs-target="#trailersCarousel"
    data-bs-slide-to="`${index}`"
    className="{ active: index === 0 }"
  >
    {index + 1}
  </li>
));
```

Instead, `return trailers.slice(0, maxCarouselItems).map((video, index) => (...));` is displayed, as *if it ware a string*.

##### Why does the return statement fail in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in an extra layer of braces. As far as JSX is concerned, you've got that `return trailers.slice...` as plain text. And the `return` here doesn't do anything, because you're already inside the return (the entirety of your JSX).

```
<div className="carousel-inner">
  {trailers.slice(0, 5).map((video, index) => (
    <div
      key="video.id"
      className="carousel-item"
      activeclassname="{ active: index === 0 }"
    >
      <iframe
        className="embed-responsive-item"
        src="`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${video.key}`"
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  ))};
</div>
```

If you wrap that in braces and also include a return, it'll give you an error. Conceptually it would be the same as this:

```
const Foo = () => {
  return (
    foo(
      return bar
    )
  )
}
```